# Decoding HTML with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to decode this HTML input string:

```
            <tbody>
     <tr  class="row0 first" >
                     <td  class="col0 first" data-colid="0" >
<span>Previous close</span>
        </td>
         <td  class="col1 last" data-colid="1" >
<span>39.64</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr  class="row1" >
                     <td  class="col0 first" data-colid="0" >
<span>Open</span>
        </td>
         <td  class="col1 last" data-colid="1" >
<span>39.50</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr  class="row2" >
                     <td  class="col0 first" data-colid="0" >
```

I tried this Regular Expression:

```
\<span\>Previous\sclose\<\/span\>[\w\n\r\<\/\s\>\=\"\-]+\<span\>[0-9\.]+\<\/span\>
```

and the output I am getting is:

```
<span>Previous close</span>
        </td>
         <td  class="col1 last" data-colid="1" >
<span>39.64</span>
```

I am interested only in the value of 39.64. Is there a way to use REGEX to only match the "39.64" without the getting the rest of the HTML?

Thx

Comment: Don't use regex. Use some toolkit to parse the data, like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: `(?<=<span>Previous\sclose<\/span>[\w\n\r\<\/\s\>\=\"\-]+<span>)[0-9\.]+(?=<\/span>)`

Comment: Ulugbek, thx. Tried your pattern with a slight change, works on Expresso, but not on Regex in c# Visual Studio. 
@"(?<=<span>Previous\sclose</span>[\s\w\n\r<>/"=-]+<span>)[0-9\.]+(?=</span>)"
The problem seems to me to be with the " character.

Comment: @eitanbarazani Yes, because of `@` you need to double `"` as follows `@"(?<=<span>Previous\sclose</span>[\s\w\n\r<>/""=-]+<span>)[0-9\.]+(?=</span>)"`

Answer (score 2):

You should try parsing the HTML instead of trying to find values inside it.

Please check the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing HTML.

Comment: Will this tool work in Windows Phone / WinRT environment?

Comment: @eitanbarazani Yes, it does. It even works in Windows Phone 7, you can get the package from nuget.

Comment: Yes! It also supports Windows Phone 7.1, WinRT and Silverlight. Check the NuGet package at http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.